# tabbar item via storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have table view controller that connected to the navigation controller, I added the tabbar and 3 tabbar items as, you can see in storyboard!

[image]

**I added navigation bar button programmatically, here is the picture:**

[image]

Right-now I have problem with my tabar items. I don't know how I can connect them to their own views! since I don't have tab bar controller as I create them via interface builder

would anyone please help me!

Comment: can't you just buils a segue by ctrl+click on the tab bar buttons and draging to desired controller?

Answer (score 1):

you should drag a UItabbarcontroller to the stroyboard instead of  the nagvigationcontroller.

then you can embbed your child viewcontrolls into navigation controller